# Trigger backbone view event manually

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, event-handling

I'm new to Backbone.js and I'm trying to trigger view change event `toggleShape`, but it's not triggering.

```
Shapes = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#shape',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'afterRender');
        var $el = this.$el;

        $.each(App.enums.itemEnums.measurement.shape, function (value, label) {
            $el.append(getRadioButton(value, 'measurement', label));
        });
        this.render();
        this.afterRender();
    },
    events: {
        'click input': 'toggleShape'
    },
    toggleShape: function (e) {
        console.log('a');
    },
    afterRender: function () {
        var value = '5';

        //$('input[value="' + value + '"]', this.$el).prop('checked', true); - DOES NOT WORK
        //this.trigger('change'); - DOES NOT WORK

        $('#shape input').eq(0).trigger('click'); // - DOES NOT WORK TOO!
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#shape input', function () {
    console.log('b');
});
```

After that in console I only can see `b`, but not `ab`.
When I click on input, I get see that everything works, but how can I trigger `toggleShape` from within view function `afterRender`?

No errors in console.

Comment: try `$('#shape input').trigger('click');`

Comment: @JqueryKing It's checking last input (that is wrong), calling `b` x2 times and not triggering `toggleShape`

Comment: Id be unique in html use class instead of id

Comment: @JqueryKing It's unique ID wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind events during the construction of the view. Use the UI object, then you should be able to call it from with the other functions of the view.

```
Shapes = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#shape',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'afterRender');
        var $el = this.$el;

        $.each(App.enums.itemEnums.measurement.shape, function (value, label) {
            $el.append(getRadioButton(value, 'measurement', label));
        });
        this.render();
        this.afterRender();
    },
    ui : {
        theInputs : '#shape input'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.theInputs': 'toggleShape'
    },
    toggleShape: function (e) {
        console.log('a');
    },
    afterRender: function () {
        var value = '5';
        this.ui.theInputs.trigger('click'); // - Should Work :)
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to optimize this code, I mean do not repeating `#shape`?

Comment: Are you using Marionette?

Comment: No, not using it and I try to avoid that (just for now)